# (Proverbs 17:19 b) "raises his door" Vs "makes his door high"/"exalts his gate"

Tags: hebrew, translation-philosophy, hebrew-bible

(Closely Related Posting:
[In Proverbs 17:19, what does "makes his door high" mean?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/44465/in-proverbs-1719-what-does-makes-his-door-high-mean)
)

> 17:19 Hebrew OT: Westminster Leningrad Codex אֹ֣הֵֽב פֶּ֭שַׁע אֹהֵ֣ב
> מַצָּ֑ה מַגְבִּ֥יהַּ פִּ֝תְחֹ֗ו מְבַקֶּשׁ־שָֽׁבֶר׃

> (Proverbs 17:19) (NASB 1995)
>
> He who loves transgression loves strife;
> He who raises his door seeks destruction.

> (Proverbs 17:19) (ESV)
>
> Whoever loves transgression loves strife; he
> who makes his door high seeks destruction.

> (Proverbs 17:19) (KJV)
>
> He loveth transgression that loveth strife: and
> he that exalteth his gate seeketh destruction.

> (Proverbs 17:19) (NKJV)
>
> He who loves transgression loves strife, And
> he who exalts his gate seeks destruction.

> 17:19 Hebrew OT: Westminster Leningrad Codex אֹ֣הֵֽב פֶּ֭שַׁע אֹהֵ֣ב
> מַצָּ֑ה מַגְבִּ֥יהַּ פִּ֝תְחֹ֗ו מְבַקֶּשׁ־שָֽׁבֶר׃

The NASB1995 use of the phrase "raises his door" as opposed to the
aforementioned bible translations' use of "makes his door
high"/"exalts his gate"  seems to have slightly different meanings.

On the biblehub.com commentaries
( https://biblehub.com/commentaries/proverbs/17-19.htm ),
some of said commentaries interpret the NASB1995 use of the phrase
"raises his door" as having something to do with speaking boastfully /
arrogantly:

> (Keil and Delitzsch Biblical Commentary on the Old Testament)  the
> reason of the pairing of these two lines in the relationship  between
> a mouth and a door (cf. Micah 7:6, פּתחי פיך). Hitzig goes  further,
> and supposes that 19b figuratively expresses what  boastfulness brings
> upon itself. Against Geier, Schultens, and others,  who understand
> פּתחו directly of the mouth, he rightly remarks that  הגדּיל פה is not
> heard of, and that הגדּיל פה taht dn would be used  instead.

while others commentaries seem to associate the other bible
translations' use of "makes his door high"/"exalts his gate" as having
something to do with behaving like a snob:

> Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers  (19) He that exalteth his
> gate.—Builds himself a sumptuous house.
>
> Benson Commentary  exalteth his gate — Namely, the gate of his house,
> that maketh it, and  consequently his house, lofty and magnificent
> beyond what becomes his  quality, that he may overtop and outshine his
> neighbours; which being  an effect and evidence of pride and
> haughtiness, is here mentioned for  all other evidences thereof. So
> the sense is, he who carries himself  loftily and scornfully; seeketh
> destruction — Seeks those things which  will expose him to
> destruction, because he makes himself odious both  to God and men.

I might be making much ado about nothing because one bible translation is talking about speaking arrogantly while the other is about behaving like a snob. Speaking arrogantly and behaving like a snob are quite closely related.

In any case, could someone please try to read and interpret the Old Testament Hebrew, and provide a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Let me begin with my usual caveat about proverbs - succinct, pithy aphorisms that are often deliberately vague to encompass as much application as possible.

Prov 17:19 is no exception - it consists 8 Hebrew words in two halves in synthetic parallelism as follows (my translation):

- [He who] loves transgression loves strife
- [He who] exalts [his] gate/door seeks destruction

In the Hebrew there is a delightful rhythm and rhyme which are impossible to translate, but we can get a hint about it from the table below

| #1 | #2 | $3 | #4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| loves | transgression | loves | strife/contention |
| exalts | gate/door | seeks | destruction |

The idea of raising the gate/door is a cultural reference of ostentation, a bit like the lines of the famous song "If I Were a Rich Man" in "Fiddler on the Roof":

- One staircase going up
- Another staircase coming down
- And anther going nowhere just for show

To build a high gate or doorway is to pretend to be very wealthy or important.  Thus, such a person is a pretentious snob, interested more in display than substance.

The conclusion here is difficult to escape - a pretentious, ostentatious person is as bad as a sinner; or, ostentation is sin!